# stream.on('connect') and stream.on('data) call order -node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with the call order of these functions (events).
somehow it appears that the event data executes before the connect.
how can I fix that? what am I missing?

does the following events order make sense (and why):

clientrequest

createServer

stream connect

stream data

clientrequest

**stream data (the previous request data )**

stream connect

stream data (the second request data)

stream write error because the stream is null (the stream was closed in the bold data event)

Comment: maybe it has something to do with  fs.readFile ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can recall in your sequence you are making a thinking mistake. A `data` event can occur multiple times because of chunked data, so you cannot rely on that.

So:

```
connect
data (can be multiple times)
end
```

In the data events you buffer all the data you get and in the `end` event you can do something with the data. The way I read your sequence now is that you are kicking off a `clientrequest` on the first chunk of data? If that's not the case please create a code sample and post it on [Gist](http://gist.github.com) or Github.

Comment: thanks for the reply and yes, of course the data can occur multiple times but you can assume here that it's only occurring once. Since I'm using the net module the request end isn't available for me. I think it's all come down to callbacks misunderstanding. any pointers?